# How to save multiple layers separately at once?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-scripting, script, mockup

i have a question. Is there an option to save multiple layers but first image need to apply do all layers below. I know there is option for that in photoshop but it's not working for me. Im creating t-shirt mockups and i will leave screenshot so you can better understand what i need if possible. So as you can see on image the frist layer called army dad need to be visible on all t-shirts below, i can turn off/on layers and save them but it will take me some time to do it because i have over 1000 images... So is there an option to somehow save them all at once but design need to be visible on all t-shirts? Thanks[image]

Comment: This should be scriptable

Comment: You question is a little confusing. However, I think having a look into [Photoshop layer comps ](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/layer-comps.html) will help.